# Recurring payments of varying amounts of money on a varying schedule

Tags: paypal

I am looking for some advice on how to add Paypal as a mean of payment on our website.

I found this [page](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/#billing-agreement-flows) which matches our use case of recurring payments of varying amounts of money on a varying schedule.
However, this is deprecated and I could not find the equivalent concept in the new APIs.

The billing agreement concept in the new API seems to be used with billing plans only which must define a specific schedule of payments which we don't want. We'd like our users to authorize us to charge their Paypal account in the future. The amounts are not defined, the schedule is not defined. We want to trigger the payments in the future.
How can we do that?

Is there a way to get an authorization token that we can then reuse to create payments of different amounts?

Thanks

Comment: There is a corresponding issue on github: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-REST-API-issues/issues/44

Answer (score 0):

The REST APIs support [Billing Agreements](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/create-billing-agreement/) and [Billing Plans](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/create-billing-plan/).  Billing Agreements are what you're after, and Billing Plans would be more like a subscription with the same amount being charged at the same interval.

That said, while it does display that Express Checkout Classic is now deprecated, that's not exactly true.  They do hope to move people into REST at some point, but it's going to be a very long time.  There are way too many people still using Classic, and they are still adding new features to it, too.  Also, things like Guest Checkout are not yet available in REST, so you have to do that with Classic.

I still use Classic myself, and I would still recommend it as of today.

Comment: The billing agreement seems to require a billing plan though: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/billing-plans-and-agreements/#billing-agreements Am I misreading the documentation?

Comment: As Michael says, it seems the REST API Billing Agreement requires a fixed amount at a set interval. Is it possible for the REST API Billing Agreement to charge a variable amount at anytime, like the classic API?